# how to paste <pre> into tinymce and preserve the formatting?

Tags: tinymce, pre, django-tinymce

This seems very hard to do.
I'm pasting html code with `<pre>` into tinymce editor.
All the whitespaces are gone inside the `<pre>`

e.g. I'm trying to copy StackOverflow's `<pre><code>`block as in

```
def foo():
  help me
```

It seems, tinymce trims whitespaces in `<pre><code><span>` and newlines are removed

How can I preserve it?
I'm using 3.5.3 btw

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should set the entity encoding setting to raw

```
tinymce.init({
    ...    
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    ...´
```

But TinyMCE adds <br /> elements on line breaks if you edit your text. Here is a setup for syntay highlighting and preformatted text in NopCommerce, it is almost the same in WordPress or whatever.

[TinyMCE Preformatted Text and Syntax Highlighting](http://www.crawler-lib.net/tinymce-syntax-highlighting-pre-tag-fix)